# Subtract Certain Values in a Row Specified by Values in Other Rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data table that looks like

```
Construct  Stain  Position  Value
VinTL       FAK    0 - 0.1    4
VinTL       ABD    0 - 0.1    2
VinTL       FAK    0 - 0.2    1
VinTL       ABD    0 - 0.2    5
VinTS       ABD    0 - 0.1    7
VinTS       FAK    0 - 0.2    3
VinTS       ABD    0 - 0.2    9
VinTS       FAK    0 - 0.1    8
```

I want to take each Stain at a certain Position (ex: Stain is FAK and Position is 0 - 0.1) and find the Value at a Construct of VinTL.  Then take the same Stain at the same Position and find the value at a Construct of VinTS.  Then I want to subtract the first Value from the second Value and create a new table.  For example, the output of this table would be

```
Stain    Position    New_Value
 FAK      0 - 0.1      -4
 FAK      0 - 0.2      -2
 ABD      0 - 0.1      -5
 ABD      0 - 0.2      -4
```

The actual data table will have many more stains and many more positions.  Each combination of Stain, Position, Construct is unique.

Comment: How do you represent your table in Matlab? Using a cell array?

Comment: use "logical arrays"

Comment: @honi I think you mean [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/). Logical arrays on their own aren't going to be of much use.

Comment: You say in your actual data table you'll have more `Stain` and more `Position`, how is `New_Value` calculated then?

Comment: I just mean that I may have another row such as stain (FAK2) with position 0.1 - 0.3 and Construct VinTS and value 5.  And then another row with the same stain, same position, construct VinTL and value 3.

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is in a table, you can do the following:

```
% convert all reapeating data to categorical arrays:
data.Construct = categorical(data.Construct);
data.Stain = categorical(data.Stain);
data.Position = categorical(data.Position);

% find all 'VinTS' value and change them to negative:
VinTS_ind = data.Construct=='VinTS';
data.Value(VinTS_ind) =  -data.Value(VinTS_ind);

% find all unique rows in 'Stain' & 'Position',
% and sum all thier instances:
[new_table,~,ci] = unique(data(:,2:3));
new_table.new_value = accumarray(ci,data.Value)
```

The result:

```
new_table =
  4×3 table
    Stain    Position    new_value
    _____    ________    _________
    ABD      0 - 0.1     -5       
    ABD      0 - 0.2     -4       
    FAK      0 - 0.1     -4       
    FAK      0 - 0.2     -2
```

BTW, you write you want to *subtract the first Value from the second Value* but in your example, you do the opposite. I followed the example in my suggestion.